# Wait for a network chage in a service, in order to download updates

Tags: android

I have a service which periodically downloads some updates from a web site.
Default period is long, about 10 mins and I do that with an AlarmManager which starts this service.

Network can be on or off, **in case it's off service should download news as soon as network returns on**, because interval is long and, in the worst case, you could have to wait 20 min till next update.

I made a network state broadcast receiver, and, with little code I made a NetworkListener interface:

```
public interface NetworkStateListener {
public void onNetworkOn();
public void onNetworkDown();
}
```

So my service has these 2 methods and **can know when network goes on or off**.

My idea is the following: in the onStart() method I spawn a new thread: if network is off thread waits, otherwise downloads. When onNetworkOn() is called I call a notify():

```
private boolean threadWaiting; //a flag so that I don't spawn multiple threads
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(!threadWaiting){//if already a thread waiting do nothing and exit
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized(binder){
                    while(!isNetworkOn())
                        try {
                            threadWaiting = true;
                            binder.wait();
                        }catch(InterruptedException ex){
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
                // blocks until network connection is available
               threadWaiting = false;
               //... operations ...
```

And this is onNetworkOn() method:

```
public void onNetworkOn() {
    synchronized(binder){
        binder.notify();
    }
```

is this the right way to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
I keep a boolean flag "missed update in my service":

```
boolean missedUpdate = false;
```

then in my onStartCommand:

```
if(isNetworkOn()){
    //do actual code
}else
    missedUpdate = true;
```

while in my on network on:

```
public void onNetworkOn(){
    if(missedUpdate){
       //download updated news
       // reset timer
       missedUpdate = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> is this the right way to proceed?

IMHO, it is not ideal, as you are keeping a service around in memory. Plus, if your service is an `IntentService`, you will have leaked a thread and may never find out about the connectivity change.

I would have a `BroadcastReceiver` set up in the manifest for `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` broadcasts, with that receiver initially disabled. If, when an alarm occurs, you find that you have no connectivity, enable that receiver. When the receiver receives the "we have a connection" broadcasts, have it call `startService()` to send a command to your service to go do the work, then have the receiver disable itself. This way, you do not need to keep the service running all of the time.